# Virtual path / application with its own settings

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently installed a certificate protecting [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com). I have a live support function setup on livesupport.example.com, which is not covered by the SSL cert. Main website is running on ASP.Net / Umbraco, and the live support solution is PHP/mySQL - yes, both running on the same server.

Is there a way for me to be able to create a virtual directory(more appropriately application), in https://www.example.com/livesupport, which would be covered by the main certificate?

So far, the tests I've made seem to retain the configuration from the main website web.config, which is undesired.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I had to create a web.config in the virtual application directory and clear all modules and settings from the main website project.
It seems to be working now.